# Why would you host html pages instead of php?

Tags: php, html

If I'm hosting a website on a server that has PHP, would I ever need to host a .html file on it?  PHP files can have raw HTML code inside of them as well as the added benefit of being able to inject PHP code, so isn't PHP a more inclusive language?

Comment: Why would you use PHP if all you *need* is HTML? There is no problem having static (HTML/JS) and dynamic (PHP) pages hosted on the same virtual paths.

Comment: There are too many good reasons for it. For example on a VERY heavily used site any and every page that does NOT require extra processing and can simply be served by the filesystem will be at least an order of magnitude faster (if not more)

Comment: From a security perspective, I would advice against making it possible to "inject" PHP code into your website.

Answer (score 7):

Serving HTML is generally a lot easier for the webserver than serving a page that has to be run through the PHP interpreter.

This can have huge benefits on high-traffic sites. For example, the [Obama campaign ran their fundraising platform with a lot of static HTML](http://kylerush.net/blog/meet-the-obama-campaigns-250-million-fundraising-platform/) for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

it always can be situation that you would need to add e.g. maintenance page in pure html

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of whether you can simply make everything "a PHP file" but rather a question of whether any given file *needs* to be PHP.  If a file contains only static content, there's no need for any server-side processing.  So in such cases it would make more sense to make it an HTML file.

Don't look for a tool that covers all cases, look for the right tool for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I read that it is recommended to have `<?php flush(); ?>` between `</head>` and `<body>`.  I would assume that this should apply to every webpage, there really isn't a solid reason as to why you would only use HTML.

I agree with *ceejayoz*, but if that's not a problem for you, then using PHP is great.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your purpose. If your page uses PHP then the file extension needs to end in .php. If you don't have any PHP then you can just save the page with a .html file extension. A major difference is that PHP is processed on the server side. Meaning the user(client) will not see your PHP code if he views the source, he'll see what was processed from the server in the form of HTML.

Comment: This isn't correct. File extensions can be spoofed with Apache Handlers, or Mod_Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of using `.php`  files over `HTML` (in this trivial case) is that, you can wrap up all your footer files(if the are the same) or any redundant files, like `sidebar`, `advertising`and just include them in your other files, instead of having to create/manage individual files later, So, you can just open one `footer.php` file and make as many changes as you want without wasting any time.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic understanding is correct. You can absolutely have a .php file that has only HTML in it and given a simple page and a simple site there would be little difference.

However, the PHP preprocessor adds a bit of overhead to check for PHP code in the file. In most cases this is insignificant, but on a highly optimized site you probably would not want the pages to be processed for nothing.

I wouldn't say that PHP is a more inclusive language though, HTML and PHP are two different things. In many cases (but by no means all) PHP generates HTML. It's just that the resulting HTML from a PHP script that has no PHP tags in it would most likely be the same as it would be for an html file. Although it is likely that HTTP Response Headers would be different and there are other things outside of the file content itself that could be slightlu